# Change prompt character in knitr for JSS

Tags: r, knitr

The Journal of Statistical Software [style guide](http://www.jstatsoft.org/style) prescripes use of `R>` as prompt character. In Sweave this can be obtained through:

```
options(prompt = "R> ", continue = "+  ", width = 70, useFancyQuotes = FALSE)
```

Is it possible to set the `prompt` character in `knitr` as well? It seems like the `prompt` argument in `chunks$set` only allows for `TRUE/FALSE`.

Comment: You might also want to try out rmarkdown + rticles (JSS template is included: https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/blob/master/R/jss_article.R)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this kind of setup in the .Rnw file:

```
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
# set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(prompt=TRUE)
options(replace.assign=TRUE, width=90, prompt="R> ")
@
```

Notice I say `prompt=TRUE` in the `opts_chunk$set()` and then specify what type of prompt in the options in the next line.

Comment: I removed the irrelevant chunk options to make it clear that the chunk option `prompt` is the key. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: @Yihui makes perfect sense thanks.  I was being lazy after I tested the solution.