# How can I force the breaklines and change the prompt character in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

Using the explanations from [Change prompt character in knitr for JSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852000/change-prompt-character-in-knitr-for-jss) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41471/getting-sweave-code-chunks-to-stay-inside-page-margins.

I am trying to breaklines and change the prompt character to `R>` in knitr. Beside that I want to use the sweave style for the code. I am using the following code in preambule:

```
library(knitr)
set.seed(123)
render_sweave()
knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {paste("\\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]\n", x, "\\end{lstlisting}\n", sep = "")})
opts_chunk$set(prompt=TRUE)
options(replace.assign=TRUE, prompt="R> ", continue = "+ ")
```

However this does not work.

Comment: What do you mean, it does not work? What happens?

Comment: The code does not break lines, but uses the  prompt character `R>`. Do you have any ideia to solve this?

Comment: From https://yihui.name/knitr/options/: "tidy.opts: (NULL; list) a list of options to be passed to tidy.source(), e.g. tidy.opts=list(blank=FALSE, width.cutoff=60); "